# Laravel 7.14 show products which are not in available in cart for user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to show the products to each user based on products in cart table. If a user has added a product in cart than it should not display in product list for that user only. I was able to show notification if the product is in cart but not being able to hide it if it's in carts table already.

Here's my CartsController:

```
// Check if item exists
    $status = Cart::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                                ->where('product_id', $product_id)->first();

    if(isset($status->user_id) && isset($request->product_id)){

        session()->flash('warning', 'You already have this item in cart.');

    }
```

My carts table has user_id and product_id.

How do I create a check if carts table has logged in user_id and product_id to hide the products?

I'm displaying all products in a table format to user with add to cart.

Cart user relation:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Cart Product relation:

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Get IDs for products in cart
$productsInCart = Cart::where('user_id',auth()->user()->id)->pluck('product_id')->toArray();
//Get products not in cart
$productsToShow = Product::whereNotIn('id',$productsInCart)->get();
```

Comment: I want to hide the products which are already in cart table for a user. If in carts table user_id matches with logged in user's id and product_id matches with product's id in carts table for that logged in user. Product will not show to that user anymore.

Comment: Thanks! I did not exactly do what you mentioned, but I was able to solve my problem. I selected all the product_id from carts table where user_id matches the logged in user and sent it to whereNotIn. Please edit your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help